# Complicated if else jQuery statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got some jQuery statements which show a div dependant on some selections a user makes from a dropdown/select field.

I was wondering if this is the correct way of doing it? The div showing depends on the answers given in all of the dropdown/select fields (3 selects/dropdowns), but sometimes the div that is only meant to show dependant on that logic shows anyway on other options within the select/dropdown.

Below is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.age').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "col1") {
      $('.subject').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "col1_ge") {
          $('.location').change(function() {
            $('#sbcox-ge').toggle($(this).val() == 'col1_sbco');
          });
        } else if ($(this).val() === "col1_ss") {
          $('.location').change(function() {
            $('#sbcox-ss').toggle($(this).val() == 'col1_sbco');
          });
        } else {}
      });
    } else if ($(this).val() === "col2") {} else {}
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subject_select").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $("#area_select").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $("#age_select").change(function() {
    $("#subject_select").children('option').hide();
    $("#subject_select").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val() + "]").show()
    $("#area_select").children('option').hide();
    $("#area_select").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val() + "]").show()
  })
})
```

```css
.inner-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="decider-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="age_select" id="age_select" class="age">
          <option value="age-fill">1. Age</option>
          <option value="col1">8</option>
          <option value="col1">9</option>
          <option value="col1">10</option>
          <option value="col2">11</option>
          <option value="col3">12</option>
          <option value="col4">13</option>
          <option value="col5">14</option>
          <option value="col6">15</option>
          <option value="col7">16</option>
          <option value="col8">17</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="subject_select" id="subject_select" class="subject">
          <option value="subject-fill">2. Subject</option>

          <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col1_subject-fill">2. Subject</option>
          <option value="col1_ge">GE</option>
          <option value="col1_ss">SS</option>

          <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col2_subject-fill">2. Subject</option>
          <option value="col2_ge">GE</option>
          <option value="col2_ss">SS</option>


          <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
          <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
          <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>

          <option value="col4_mss">layout test 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="area_select" id="area_select" class="location">
          <option value="location-fill">3. Location</option>

          <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col1_location-fill">3. Location</option>
          <option value="col1_sbco">SBCO</option>

          <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col2_location-fill">3. Location</option>
          <option value="col2_sbco">SBCO</option>
          <option value="col2_sbcc">SBCC</option>

          <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
          <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
          <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" id="button-overall">
        <div class="call-to-action">

          <a class="call-action" href="#">See Your Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 inner-modal" id="sbcox-ge">
        <div class="call-to-action">
          <a class="call-action" href="link here" target="_blank">See GE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 inner-modal" id="sbcox-ss">
        <div class="call-to-action">
          <a class="call-action" href="link here" target="_blank">See SS</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--End Row-->
  </div>
  <!--End Container-->
</div>
<!--End Decider Form-->
```

Comment: It's almost never right to bind one event handler inside another event handler.

Comment: Adding event handlers inside another event handler is almost always a really bad idea. They're *cumulative*: adding a handler does not remove existing handlers.

Comment: Thank you, how would you write the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of CSS and data-* attribute you can write cleaner code. I added `data-column` to subject and location. Once age is changed both are populated and then with CSS the options are shown or hidden.

Also, as said with other answers don't nest event handlers. One of the uses of event handlers is to eliminate the need for if/else in some cases.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let age_select = $("#age_select");
  let subject_select = $("#subject_select");
  let area_select = $("#area_select");

  age_select.on("change", function() {
    let currentCol = jQuery(this).val();
  // When age is changed reset other dropdown (by setting value to the default one)
  // and trigger change for the event handler to be called
    subject_select.attr("data-column", currentCol).val('subject-fill').trigger('change');
    area_select.attr("data-column", currentCol).val('location-fill').trigger('change');
  });
 
 
 // if subject is changed reset location and trigger change
  subject_select.on("change", function() {
    area_select.val('location-fill').trigger('change');
  });

  area_select.on("change", function() {
    let currentLocation = jQuery(this).val();
    let subject = subject_select.val();
  
  // If dropdown change is triggers then check if it is default value
  // if so then hide links
    if (currentLocation == 'location-fill') {
      $('#sbcox-ge,#sbcox-ss').toggle(false);
      return;
    }
  
  // if not default value then show the related link based on subject selection
    $('#sbcox-ge').toggle(subject.indexOf("ge") > -1);
    $('#sbcox-ss').toggle(subject.indexOf("ss") > -1);
  });
})
```

```css
.inner-modal {
  display: none;
}

#subject_select option:not([value='subject-fill']) {
  display: none;
}

#area_select option:not([value='location-fill']) {
  display: none;
}

#subject_select[data-column='col1'] option[value^='col1'],
#subject_select[data-column='col2'] option[value^='col2'],
#subject_select[data-column='col3'] option[value^='col3'] {
  display: block;
}

#area_select[data-column='col1'] option[value^='col1'],
#area_select[data-column='col2'] option[value^='col2'],
#area_select[data-column='col3'] option[value^='col3'] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="decider-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="age_select" id="age_select" class="age">
          <option value="age-fill">1. Age</option>
          <option value="col1">8</option>
          <option value="col1">9</option>
          <option value="col1">10</option>
          <option value="col2">11</option>
          <option value="col3">12</option>
          <option value="col4">13</option>
          <option value="col5">14</option>
          <option value="col6">15</option>
          <option value="col7">16</option>
          <option value="col8">17</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="subject_select" id="subject_select" class="subject" data-column=''>
          <option value="subject-fill">2. Subject</option>

          <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col1_ge">GE</option>
          <option value="col1_ss">SS</option>

          <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col2_ge">GE</option>
          <option value="col2_ss">SS</option>


          <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
          <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
          <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>

          <option value="col4_mss">layout test 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="area_select" id="area_select" class="location" data-column=''>
          <option value="location-fill">3. Location</option>

          <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col1_sbco">SBCO</option>

          <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col2_sbco">SBCO</option>
          <option value="col2_sbcc">SBCC</option>

          <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
          <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
          <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" id="button-overall">
        <div class="call-to-action">

          <a class="call-action" href="#">See Your Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 inner-modal" id="sbcox-ge">
        <div class="call-to-action">
          <a class="call-action" href="link here" target="_blank">See GE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 inner-modal" id="sbcox-ss">
        <div class="call-to-action">
          <a class="call-action" href="link here" target="_blank">See SS</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--End Row-->
  </div>
  <!--End Container-->
</div>
<!--End Decider Form-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! :) 
Is there a way to not make all the buttons show, so if I chose 8, SS & SBCO then all three buttons show? Thank you.

Comment: Which buttons? Do you mean dropdowns?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear! So if you choose Age = 8, Subject = SS & Location = SBCO. Then all the three links show, I'd only like the 'See SS' to show.
Then if the user was to go back to step two, straight after selecting the above and changed it to GE, would just the 'See Ge' link show then.

Comment: @M.T I updated the code with you asked. Even though this can be accomplished by jQuery, libraries like vue.js handle it much better.

Comment: Thank you! Where would you suggest the best place would be to read about/learn about vue.js? Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: You can learn about vue.js in their documentation. It is an excellent guide. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind event handlers inside other event handlers. Just have the dependent events check the values of the other inputs when they run.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".location").change(function() {
    var age = $(".age").val();
    var subject = $(".subject").val();
    if (age == "col1") {
      if (subject == "col1_ge") {
        $("#sbcox-ge").toggle($(this).val() == "col1_sbco");
      } else if (subject == "col1_ss") {
        $("#sbcox-ss").toggle($(this).val() == "col1_sbco");
      } else {}
    } else if (age == "col2") {} 
      else {}
  });

  $("#subject_select").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $("#area_select").children('option:gt(0)').hide();
  $("#age_select").change(function() {
    $("#subject_select").children('option').hide();
    $("#subject_select").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val() + "]").show()
    $("#area_select").children('option').hide();
    $("#area_select").children("option[value^=" + $(this).val() + "]").show()
  })
})
```

```css
.inner-modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="decider-form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="age_select" id="age_select" class="age">
          <option value="age-fill">1. Age</option>
          <option value="col1">8</option>
          <option value="col1">9</option>
          <option value="col1">10</option>
          <option value="col2">11</option>
          <option value="col3">12</option>
          <option value="col4">13</option>
          <option value="col5">14</option>
          <option value="col6">15</option>
          <option value="col7">16</option>
          <option value="col8">17</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="subject_select" id="subject_select" class="subject">
          <option value="subject-fill">2. Subject</option>

          <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col1_subject-fill">2. Subject</option>
          <option value="col1_ge">GE</option>
          <option value="col1_ss">SS</option>

          <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col2_subject-fill">2. Subject</option>
          <option value="col2_ge">GE</option>
          <option value="col2_ss">SS</option>


          <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
          <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
          <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>

          <option value="col4_mss">layout test 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <select name="area_select" id="area_select" class="location">
          <option value="location-fill">3. Location</option>

          <!--Below shows when '1 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col1_location-fill">3. Location</option>
          <option value="col1_sbco">SBCO</option>

          <!--Below shows when '2 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col2_location-fill">3. Location</option>
          <option value="col2_sbco">SBCO</option>
          <option value="col2_sbcc">SBCC</option>

          <!--Below shows when '3 column' is selected is hidden otherwise-->
          <option value="col3_mss">layout 3</option>
          <option value="col3_ssm">layout 4</option>
          <option value="col3_sms">layout 5</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" id="button-overall">
        <div class="call-to-action">

          <a class="call-action" href="#">See Your Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 inner-modal" id="sbcox-ge">
        <div class="call-to-action">
          <a class="call-action" href="link here" target="_blank">See GE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 inner-modal" id="sbcox-ss">
        <div class="call-to-action">
          <a class="call-action" href="link here" target="_blank">See SS</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--End Row-->
  </div>
  <!--End Container-->
</div>
<!--End Decider Form-->
```

Comment: Is there anyway to reset the data? So if the user does Age = 8, Subject = SS, then Location = SBCO, but changes their mind about subject and goes and chooses GE then the 'See SS' button still shows.

Comment: Hide the other DIV: `$("#sbcox-ge").toggle($(this).val() == "col1_sbco"); $("#sbcox-ss").hide()`